# jQuery/ColdFusion Image Crop Relative To Source Resolution

Tags: jquery, image, coldfusion

I'm using an image crop plugin for jQuery called imgAreaSelect. It does the job and ultimately returns the crop area in the format `{ x, y, width, height }`.

When I post this data to ColdFusion I then perform the crop routine on the source image which is copied to an `_edited` directory.

The problem I'm having is that the front-end crop coordinates and dimensions do not align properly with the source image on the back-end. Since the image on the front-end has to be scaled down to fit on the screen, I can't exactly crop over an original size.

Is there some crazy math gurus out there that know a formula to calculate the offset or something? Or perhaps if there is another way of doing this, maybe I'm doing it wrong...

Comment: We use Jcrop here, this has an attribute you can pass in called trueSize which is then used to offset all the sizes, so when passed back to us the x and y match.  Does imgAreaSelect have something similar?

Comment: No it doesn't but I'll check out jCrop, Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for following up. Though if @JedihomerTownend's suggestion worked for you, might want to let them promote their comment to an "answer" :)

Answer (score 0):

> We use Jcrop here, this has an attribute you can pass in called trueSize which is then used to offset all the sizes, so when passed back to us the x and y match. Does imgAreaSelect have something similar?

**Worked a treat**